# Workbox Cache load is too big

Tags: symfony, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

Good day.. I have a problem with my workbox. When i set the strategy to NetworkFirst, every time i click on a page, it caches atleast 20MB of files. if i click on the same page, it again saves another cache at least 20MB. Same with StaleWhileRevalidate but worse. If i use CacheFirst, pages only caches 1-2MB but if there are changes on the page, it wont reflect. if i delete the old cache, it will now reflect.

here is my sample code. hope that you can help me with this.

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.4.1/workbox-sw.js');

if (workbox) {
  const CACHE_PREFIX = 'v01';

  workbox.setConfig({
    clientsClaim: true,
    debug: true,
    skipWaiting: true
  });
  workbox.core.setLogLevel(workbox.core.LOG_LEVELS.warn);

  // Javascript and CSS rule
  workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    new RegExp('^.*(?:js|css)'),
    new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst(
      { cacheName: `${CACHE_PREFIX}-asset` }
    ),
  );

  // Main rule - to cache everything,
  // i dont know why on this part, it wont cache CSS and JS
  // sw.js is also cached here
  workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    new RegExp('^.*(?:)'),
    new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst(
      { cacheName: `${CACHE_PREFIX}-main` }
    ),
  );

} else {
  console.log(`Boo! Workbox didn't load `);
}
```

if you have any caching tips for me it would be helpful.

My project structure with Symfony if it helps:

```
root/sw.js and manifest.json
root/js/assetic files (ex 909ab227.js)
root/css/assetic files (ex 307a9c17.css)
root/../var/cache/dev/twig/a lot of folders (ex alphanumeric.php)
```

Answer (score 1):

Good day.. Got it to work on my project.

added these lines of code inside `workbox.routing.registerRoute`

```
new workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin({
  statuses: [200]
})
```

Ⅰ still dont know how to precache my assetic files on Symfony though.